# In this sentence she gets depressed/disappointed when she says the last sentence or just the last words?

Tags: translation

In the sentence 最後の言葉の時だけほんの少し俯いたけど when she says she got depressed or disappointed, it refers to how many words of the last sentence she said (or maybe the whole sentence as she had said 3 long sentences in a row).

Comment: It totally depends on context.

Comment: Without any context it just means the last words? The girls makes a sigh and the last words are separated by the ellipsis (...) so normally it would just refer to that? (you can tell me just the general use).

Comment: 言葉 is "a piece of speech" so it can really mean anything from a single particle to a 90-minute lecture. If you believe a certain part is independent or outstanding enough from the other, then it could be that piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when someone is emotionally affected by 最後の言葉, it means not the exact the last word, but the last whole sentence or some of last sentences which convey one meaningful content.

We use the similar expression like this as

> 結婚式{けっこんしき}で新婦{しんぷ}はお父{とう}さんの**最後{さいご}の言葉{ことば}**‌の時{とき}だけ少{すこ}し涙{なみだ}が出{で}た.

In this case general translation will be like;

> The bride cried a little only at **the last part of her father's speech** at the wedding ceremony.